# A solution for nonlinear multivariable system of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

I want to solve this system of equations. I took these equations as a result of a problem I was trying to solve. I write equations in the simplest possible form.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be Real or Complex coefficients,where $A\neq 0$, $B\neq 0$ and $x,y,z,u,v$ be variables, where  $x\neq 0,y\neq 0,z\neq 0,u\neq 0,v\neq 0.$

I want to solve this system of equations:

> $$\begin{cases}3z^2uB+3x+2uzA+xz^2A=0 &(1)\\
> 3y+2vzA+u^2A+2xzuA+yz^2A+3vz^2B+3x^2+3zu^2B=0 &(2)\\
> 3y^2+v^2A+2xuvA+2yzvA+3v^2zB+yu^2A+3vu^2B+3x^2y=0 &(3)\\
> 3xy^2+xv^2A+2yuvA+3v^2uB=0 &(4)\end{cases} $$

$\Huge{\text{My attempts:}}$

$3y^2+2vzyA+u^2yA+2xzuyA+y^2z^2A+3vz^2yB+3x^2y+3zu^2yB-3y^2-v^2A-2xuvA-2yzvA+3v^2zB-yu^2A-3vu^2B-3x^2y=0\Longrightarrow (yz-v)(2xuA+3vzB+yzA+vA+3u^2B)=0$

Let, $yz=v$,  then applying $v=yz$  we get from $(1)$ and $(4)$

$yz^2A+zvA=0 \Longrightarrow zy+v=0 \Longrightarrow 2v=0 \Longrightarrow v=0$ which is contradiction. So, $yz\neq v$

We get,  $2xuA+3vzB+yzA+vA+3u^2B=0.$

There exist a solution for $v=0, x=0, z=0$ and $3y+u^2A=0$ which gives infinitely many solutions. $x=y=z=u=v=0$ is trival solution.

I can not continue from  $yz\neq v$.

I am looking for a solution for non-zero variables $x,y,z,u,v$ where $A\neq0, B\neq 0.$ The solution does not have to be in the real numbers set.

For special case $A=B=1$ we have,

> $$\begin{cases}3z^2u+3x+2uz+xz^2=0 &(1)\\
> 3y+2vz+u^2+2xzu+yz^2+3vz^2+3x^2+3zu^2=0 &(2)\\
> 3y^2+v^2+2xuv+2yzv+3v^2z+yu^2+3vu^2+3x^2y=0 &(3)\\
> 3xy^2+xv^2+2yuv+3v^2u=0 &(4)\end{cases} $$

Is it possible to solve this system of equations for non-zero variables?

Comment: Should the solution hold for arbitrary non-zero $A$ and $B$, or are you allowing a relation on $A$ and $B$, e.g., $A^2=B^3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde no no I am looking for a general solution. $A$ and $B$ dont depend each other.

Comment: You have five unknowns, $x,y,z,u,v$, and only four equations. In principle you must have an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @Piquito I think this rule works for only linear system of equations. This system is not linear.

Comment: I suppose you are satisfied with just one solutions and not with infinitely many? All solutions I have found so far result in a dependency of $A$ and $B$. But I have to check if this is correct.

Comment: @Learner On the contrary, this is a more-or-less "general" rule of thumb. To see why, think geometrically. Suppose you have $3$ variables. Then one equation in these is a surface in $3$-d space. If you intersect this with another such surface, you still have infinitely many solutions (in their common lines). Thus, you need one more equation to get a countably infinite number of solutions, at the most. With most equations you're like to come across, $3$ such equations will determine at most a finite set of solutions -- povided, of course, that these equations describe truly different surfaces.

Comment: By the way, instead of trying to do this manually, since you're doing this to solve some other problem, why not use a CAS, like Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @Allawonder But the solutions should hold simultaneously for infinitely many (arbitrary) parameters $A$ and $B$, i.e., $x=f(A,B)$ etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think you found a solution. I mean the solution doesnt exist for non zero variables, according to your work.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't understand what you're referring to. My comment was in response to the OP's comment to the effect that they need not specify as many equations as unknowns in a system to determine finitely many solutions in general.

Comment: @Allawonder of course I tried. For example $A=B=22$ and WA  collapsed.

Comment: @Learner Does the problem you want need arbitrary parameters $AB\ne 0$? It might be simpler to solve if you already know specific values of $A,B.$

Comment: @Allawonder $A=B=9$ Can you solve.......? I can not. WA can not.

Comment: @Learner If that's it, it's better to put it in the post instead of arbitrary $A,B.$ As for solving, you will have infinitely many solutions. I'll look into it, but cannot promise anything tonight. In fact, I'm already in bed, waiting for Sleep.

Comment: Simplify by [Resultant](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/11.1567997986.png) in Wolfram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment. For some values of $A$ and $B$ it is trivial to find solutions. For example, for $A=2$ and $B=-3$ we can take $x=2,y=1,z=1,u=2,v=1$. For $A=B=1$ one can take
$$
x= 1,\; y= 1, \; z = - \frac{1}{3}, u=\frac{28}{3}, v=-\frac{1}{3}.
$$
In this case we have infinitely many solutions for $A=B=1$, e.g.,
$$
y=x,\; v=xz,\; u=-\frac{xz^2+3x}{3z^2+2z}, \, z^3+z^2+1=0
$$
for arbitrary $x\neq 0$.

Comment: yes it is very nice to share it. By the way, did you check my attempts?

Comment: Yes, for $v=yz$ we do not have a solution, you are right.

Comment: thank you for checking.

Comment: Are these the only solutions even in this specific case?

Comment: If $A=2$ and $B=-3$ then, because $x,y,z,u,v\neq 0$ we obtain $27yz + 8vz - 12y + 27v=0$ and several other equations of this type. I think there are more solutions, but I would need to check.

Comment: I couldn't go any further. After $v\neq yz$ Everything's confused. I think you've gone all the way. It seems you have proved that there is no general solution for any $A$ and $B.$

Comment: No, I haven't so far. I can try later.

Comment: I can not use math software.Do you think Maple or Mathematica can solve this?

Comment: Do you think it is possible to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-Since you have more unknowns than equations, this difficult system can be partially attacked considering arbitrary values of certain unknowns. For example for $(x, y, z, u) = (1,2,3,4)$ you get the "simple" system (except calculation error)
$$\begin{cases}108B+33A+3=0\\144B+27Bv+6Av+58A+9=0\\48Bv+9Bv^2+14Av+Av^2+32A+18=0\\16Av+12Bv^2+Av^2+12=0\end{cases}$$

And you still have to see if it is compatible because it has four equations with three unknowns.Once you finish this then you can propose a system with established $A, B$ and $v$ which would give you a correct system to solve. Every solving algebraic equation would have solutions because you work in $\mathbb C$ which is algebraically closed.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are coefficients.$ x,y,z,u,v$ are variables.

Comment: Arbitrary parameters $A$ and $B$ will not satisfy $108B+33A+3=0$.