# What is the method to solve this system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

$\Huge{\text{Updated:}}$

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3348636/510100) I got an answer [for special non-zero values](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3348739/510100) of $A$ and $B.$  I need to solve these polynomial equations for any arbitrary non-zero coefficients.

> $\underline{\text{ I am looking for a solution that does not lead to the solution of a cubic equation.}}$

Here is the problem:

> For all arbitrary non-zero coefficients $A$ and $B$,   I am looking for a method to solve this system of equations, where $x\neq 0,y\neq 0,z\neq 0, u\neq 0, v\neq 0.$
>
> $$\begin{cases}3z^2uB+3x+2uzA+xz^2A=0 &(1)\\
> 3y+2vzA+u^2A+2xzuA+yz^2A+3vz^2B+3x^2+3zu^2B=0 &(2)\\
> 3y^2+v^2A+2xuvA+2yzvA+3v^2zB+yu^2A+3vu^2B+3x^2y=0 &(3)\\
> 3xy^2+xv^2A+2yuvA+3v^2uB=0 &(4)\end{cases} $$

$\Huge{\text{My old attempts:}}$

$3y^2+2vzyA+u^2yA+2xzuyA+y^2z^2A+3vz^2yB+3x^2y+3zu^2yB-3y^2-v^2A-2xuvA-2yzvA-3v^2zB-yu^2A-3vu^2B-3x^2y=0\Longrightarrow (yz-v)(2xuA+3vzB+yzA+vA+3u^2B)=0$

Let, $v=yz$  we get from $(1)$ and $(4)$

$yz^2A+zvA=0 \Longrightarrow zy+v=0 \Longrightarrow 2v=0 \Longrightarrow v=0$ which is contradiction. So, $yz\neq v$

and  $2xuA+3vzB+yzA+vA+3u^2B=0$ must be.

$\Huge{\text{My new attempts:}}$

$z(2xuA+3vzB+yzA+vA+3u^2B)-(3y+2vzA+u^2A+2xzuA+yz^2A+3vz^2B+3x^2+3zu^2B)=0 \Longrightarrow 3y+zvA+u^2A+3x^2=0$

$v(2xuA+3vzB+yzA+vA+3u^2B)-(3y^2+v^2A+2xuvA+2yzvA+3v^2zB+yu^2A+3vu^2B+3x^2y)=0 \Longrightarrow 3y+zvA+u^2A+3x^2=0$

Finally, I can construct a new system of equations: (If I didn't make any mistake)

> $$\begin{cases}3z^2uB+3x+2uzA+xz^2A=0 &\\
> 3y+2vzA+u^2A+2xzuA+yz^2A+3vz^2B+3x^2+3zu^2B=0 &\\
> 3y^2+v^2A+2xuvA+2yzvA+3v^2zB+yu^2A+3vu^2B+3x^2y=0 &\\
> 3xy^2+xv^2A+2yuvA+3v^2uB=0 &\end{cases} \Longrightarrow \begin{cases}3z^2uB+3x+2uzA+xz^2A=0 &(1)\\
> 2xuA+3vzB+yzA+vA+3u^2B=0 &(2)\\
> 3y+zvA+u^2A+3x^2=0 &(3)\\
> 3xy^2+xv^2A+2yuvA+3v^2uB=0 &(4)\end{cases} $$

Here I am stuck. I've worked hard to make variables dependent on a single variable. Having a single variable requires a method. I can't find a method right now.

Comment: Groebner bases is the magic word.

Comment: @Wuestenfux What is the Groebner..? Sorry English is not my native language.

Comment: Basically its one of the triumphs of computational algebraic geometry. It allows you  to solve systems of polynomial equations by elimination.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Do I need to do this with the help of computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still eliminate. From $(1)$ we have
$$
y = \frac{ - 3x^2 - A(u^2 + vz)}{3},
$$
and then from $(3)$ we have
$$
x = \frac{uz( - 2A - 3Bz)}{Az^2 + 3}.
$$
Actually, the case of $Az^2+3=0$ leads to $Bz^3-2=0$.
Otherwise we have only two equations left in three variables $z,u,v$, namely $(2),(4)$ and can take the resultant. Then one can even specify something, e.g., $u=z$ and $v=-z$ to obtain a general solution. Here is one example:
$$
u=z,\; v=-z\; \text{ with $z$ such that } Bz^3 + Az^2 +1=0.
$$
Then $x=1$ and $y=-1$.

Edit: The general solution. After eliminating $x$ and $y$ as above we can eliminate $v$ by
$$
v:= \frac{u^2(A^4z^5 + 30A^3z^3 + 45A^2Bz^4 + 45A^2z + 27ABz^5 - 81B}{- A^4z^6 - 3A^3z^4 + 9A^2Bz^5 + 9A^2z^2 + 54ABz^3 + 27A + 81Bz},
$$
provided the denominator is nonzero. In this case we obtain a **single** equation, which gives all solutions, namely
$$
(AZ^2 + Bz^3  + 1)(2A^6z^6 + 90A^5z^4 + 162A^4Bz^5 + 270A^4z^2 + 108A^3B^2z^6 + 540A^3Bz^3 + 54A^3 + 1215A^2B^2z^4 - 486A^2Bz + 1458AB^3z^5 + 729B^4z^6 + 729B^2)=0.
$$
Note that this is independent of the variable $u$. In case that the denominator is zero, we have a special case "avoiding the cubic", but introducing a dependency of $A$ and $B$, which was not allowed.

Comment: Does it seem possible to switch to a single variable?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Is it possible to escape the cubic equation?

Comment: In fact I don't want to have all the solutions. A single solution without a cubic equation can save me from this problem..

Comment: Specifying one variable it seems one always ends up with a polynomial  equation in one variable of degree at least $3$.

Comment: It is a mystery for me..:) For $A=B=1$ You found a solution which is doesnt include cubic equation. (and on the contrary,) Is it possible to do it again?

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I mean You have successfully escaped the cubic equation for $A = B = 1.$ Is it possible to do it for all nonzero $A,B$ values? Actually, I wanted to ask You that.

Comment: So, for $A = B = 1$ and for only ***some special nonzero values*** of $A$ and $B$ ,we can escape cubic equation. Do I understand correct?

Comment: Teacher, I want to solve this system of equations for all non-zero $A$ and $B$ by avoiding the cubic equation. Which You've done before for $A=B=1$.

Comment: Does it seem impossible?

Comment: I can not understand you.

Comment: I don't understand you, too :) I am afraid that we cannot avoid a polynomial equation (so not only cubic, but also perhaps quartic and higher) for general $A$ and $B$. If you satisfy some cubic in $A$ and $B$ like $A^2=B^3$ by setting, say, $A=B=1$, then it becomes possible, but not for general $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I think now understood.For only $A^2=B^3$ we can escape cubic equation. Did you mean?

Comment: Yes, in the last step eliminating $v$ one divides by something, which might be zero if, say, $A^2=B^3$. If not, one can divide and gets the cubic equation. Otherwise one can avoid it.